# Weak-* closed subspaces and Preduals, a la von Neumann Algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $X$  be a Banach Space. Suppose that $M \leq X^*$ is a weak-* closed subspace. Is it true that $M$ has a predual? According to my understanding, taking the pre-annihilator $M^\perp = \{x \in X \vert  \forall a \in M, \, a(x)=0\}$ we should get that $M_* = X/M^\perp$ satisfies $(M_*)^* \simeq M$. I couldn't prove it. Further, what is really bothering me is if one looks at the *restriction* of the functionals $X \subset X^{**}$ under the canonical injection, to be functionals on $M$, is it true that this space can be identified as Banach spaces with $M_*$?

I am asking this since this somehow should be the situation for von Neumann Algebras, where the above translates to **Why can we identify the predual $M_*$ of a a von Neuman Algebra both as the space of ultraweakly continuous functionals on $M$, and as the quotient Banch space $L^1(\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}))/M^\perp$ of the trace class operators**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $M^\perp$ is closed, as such $X/M^\perp$ is a normed space and also Banach. Further every element $a\in M$ induces a map $X/M^\perp\to\Bbb C$, $[x]\mapsto a(x)$. This map has the same norm as $a$ as can be checked, hence you may identify $M$ with a sub-space of $(X/M^\perp)^*$. What is left to check is that every element of $(X/M^\perp)^*$ comes from an element of $M$; here is where the weak* closedness of $M$ will enter.

Specifically if $M$ is weak* closed and $V\subseteq X/M^\perp$ is finite dimensional and $q:V\to\Bbb C$ linear then there is an $a\in M$ with $a\lvert_V=q$. We'll do this proof for completeness.

If $\dim(V)=1$ this is clear, as there must be an $a\in M$ with $a\lvert_V\neq0$, else $\pi^{-1}(V)\subseteq M^\perp$ which is a contradiction ($\pi:X\to X/M^\perp$ the projection). For $\dim(V)>1$ do an induction, assume that for each strict subspace of $V$ we can find an $a$ agreeing with $q$ on that subspace.

So let $e_1,...,e_n$ be a basis of $V$, there must be some $b\in M$ with $b(e_1)=...=b(e_{n-1})=0$ and $b(e_n)\neq0$, as otherwise whenever two elements of $M$ agree on $\mathrm{span}(e_1,...,e_{n-1})$ they agree on $\mathrm{span}(e_1,...,e_n)$ and there must be a linear formula so that $a(e_n)=\sum_i x_i\,a(e_i)$, hence $a(e_n-\sum_ix_i e_i)=0$ for all $a\in M$ and $e_n-\sum_i x_ie_i$ is $0$ in $X/M^\perp$, contradicting that $e_1,...,e_n$ is a basis.

So if $a\in M$ with $a\lvert_{\mathrm{span}(e_1,...,e_{n-1}})=q\lvert_{\mathrm{span}(e_1,...,e_{n-1}})$, then $[a + (q(e_n)-a(e_n))b]\lvert_V =q$ completing the induction.

Now if $q\in (X/M^\perp)^*$ let $\mathcal V$ denote the directed set of finite dimensional sub-spaces of $X/M^\perp$ and for each $V\in\mathcal V$ let $a_V\in M$ be such that $a_V\lvert_V=q\lvert_V$. Then $a_V$ converges pointwise to $q$ on $X/M^\perp$, by weak* closure you get that $q\in M$.

(Small remark: In the end I am a bit sloppy with identifications. For $q\in X/M^\perp$ the above procedure will give a net $a_V\in M$ so that $a_V \to q\circ \pi$ as elements of $X^*$, giving a pre-image of $q$ in $M$ under the identification of $M$ with a sub-space of $X/M^\perp$.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear proof! Regarding the continuation of my question, do you happen to know why the identification $L^1 (\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})) / M^\perp \to M_*$ given by $a \to (x \to Tr(ax) \vert _M)$ is isometric? I understand it's surjective by Hahn Banach, but I don't see why the ultraweakly continuous extension of $a \in M_*$ can be chosen to have the same norm.

Comment: Note that $L^1(H)$ (the space of traceclass operators) is the predual of $B(H)$, which gives you that the ultra-weak operator and the weak* topology on $B(H)$ agree. Hence von Neumann algebras, which are ultra-weak closed, are weak* closed and the above discussion applies. I didn't carry out the step giving that the inclusion $M\to (X/M^\perp)^*$ is isometric, but it can be seen like this. If $a\in M$ you have for any $[x]\in X/M^\perp$ that $\|[x]\|=\liminf_{x\in[x]} \|x\|$ hence $|a([x])|=|a(x)|=\liminf_{x\in[x]}|a(x)|≤\|a\|\liminf\|x\|$ and the map is a contraction. For the other direction

Comment: let $x\in X$ so that $|a(x)|>\|a\|\,\|x\|-\epsilon$, then $\|[x]\|≤\|x\|$ hence $|a([x])|≥ \|a\|\,\|[x]\| -\epsilon$

Comment: the fact that $M \to (X/M^\perp)^*$ is isometric I understood (when you wrote your original answer). What I am trying to ask about is a different thing (which is the "Further" part of my original question): A lot of textbooks define the predual as the space of ultraweakly continuous functions, I am asking why, as a normed space w.r.t operator norm, it is isomorphic to the quotient construction we have here for the predual. Should I post as a separate question?

Comment: If $V$ is a Banach space and you give $V^*$ the weak* topology, then $(V^*)^*\cong V$, ie the only weak* continuous functionals are point evaluations. If $f: M\to\Bbb C$ is ultra-weak continuous functional you can use Hahn Banach to extend to an ultra-weak continuous functional $B(H)\to \Bbb C$. Since the ultra-weak topology on $B(H)$ is the weak* topology this functional must then be the evaluation functional of an element of $L^1(H)$.This allows you to see that every ultra-weakly continuous functionals on $M$ is given by the action of an element of $L^1(H)$. However that action isn't [...]

Comment: [...] effective so you still need to get rid of its kernel. So you get that the ultra-weakly continuous functionals on $M$ are of the form $L^1(H)/M^\perp$. You can now give this a norm in the usual way (namely $\|a\|=\sup_{x\in M}\frac{|a(x)|}{\|x\|}$), and it should follow from arguments of the form above that this is the same norm that $L^1(H)/M^\perp$ gets as a quotient of $L^1(H)$. So if you wan't to build a pre-dual you can use the ultra-weakly continuous functions and get the same thing as the above discussion. Or am I still missing the question?

Comment: The proof you described here is exactly what should answer my question. However, what I can't seem to understand (and was basically my motivation for posting the original question) is why should the identification you described above be norm preserving? Why given $\varphi : M \to \mathbb{C}$ ultraweakly continuous, after you extend it by Hahn Banach, why should there exist an extension such that $\Vert \varphi \Vert_{op,\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})} = \Vert \varphi \Vert_{op,\mathcal{M}}$? As I understand this is saying the map is  norm preserving.

Comment: I don't see exactly how this would have a similar proof for the fact that $(X / M^\perp)^* \simeq M$ is isomteric, as you proved above.

Comment: Indeed, it is not clear if the extension can be chose to be norm preserving, and I cannot find the relevant version of Hahn Banach for lcs. But it is not necessary. What you have is 1. Every ultra-weakly continuous functional on $M$ is of the form $x\mapsto\langle a, x\rangle$ for some (not unique) $a\in L^1(H)$. 2. The induced inclusion $L^1(H)\to M^*$ is a contraction. 3. This implies that $M^\perp$ is closed and then every ultraweakly continuous functional is uniquely assigned to an element of $L^1(H)/M^\perp$. 4. The action of $M$ on $L^1(H)/M^\perp$ (with quotient norm) gives an isometric

Comment: identification of $M$ with $(L^1(H)/M^\perp)^*$. 5. The quotient norm of an elmenent of $L^1(H)/M^\perp$ then agrees with the norm $\|a\|=\sup_{x\in M}\frac{|a(x)|}{\|x\|}$, for example because the canonical inclusion into the double dual is isometric. 6. This norm is the same norm you equip linear functionals on $M$ with. So in total: The ultraweakly continuous functionals are $L^1(H)/M^\perp$ and the quotient norm on $L^1(H)/M^\perp$ is the same as the norm you give functionals.

Comment: I want to deeply thank you for this discussion. I have been stuck for weeks because of this gap in the literature I read regarding the predual. Again, thank you for clearing every last doubt I have!